# Using a WeakMap to track function invocations

Tags: javascript, weakmap

In order to learn about using [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections#weakmap_object), I came up with the following example to track function invocations:

```js
var map = new WeakMap();

function countFunctionInvocations(func) {
    return function(...args) {
        map.set(func, (map.get(func) || 0)+1);
        return func.apply(this, args);
    }
};


const _add = (x,y) => x+y;
const _inc = x     => x+1;


const add = countFunctionInvocations(_add);
const inc = countFunctionInvocations(_inc);

add(2,3);
add(1,2);
add(2,3);
add(2,3);
inc(inc(1));
console.log(map.get(_add), map.get(_inc));
// 4 2
```

What would be a cleaner way to implement this, as I have to alias the functions back and forth, for example from `add` to `_add` and back to `add`. Additionally, is the above a legitimate usage of Weakmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the WeakMap is pretty weird - as you've noticed, if you want to look things up with it with functions, you have to store those functions in variables, which are separate from the count-invokified function. It makes things awkward and a WeakMap doesn't seem to have a net benefit over a plain object, as long as you don't have function name collisions.

If this is allowed by what you're looking for, you could pass another argument to `countFunctionInvocations` indicating the name, allowing you to pass a (concise, anonymous) arrow function.

```js
const counts = {};

function countFunctionInvocations(name, func) {
    return function(...args) {
        counts[name] = (counts[name] ?? 0) + 1;
        console.log("called", name, counts[name]);
        return func.apply(this, args);
    }
};

const add = countFunctionInvocations('add', (x,y) => x+y);
const inc = countFunctionInvocations('inc', x => x + 1);

add(2,3);
add(1,2);
add(2,3);
add(2,3);
inc(inc(1));
console.log(counts.add, counts.inc);
```

> Additionally, is the above a legitimate usage of Weakmap?

I mean, it could be used, but as we've noticed - it's awkward to have to have two separate references to a function - one being the base function, and one being the one transformed by `countFunctionInvocations`.

That said, this is certainly a legitimate usage of WeakMap *over a Map*, because it allows the function (and its invoke count) to be garbage collected once nothing else can reference it.

I guess another option would be for the returned function to be the one put into the Map, so that you only have one identifier on the outside, but it'd require a `function` or a second argument to indicate the name of the function, otherwise the inside of `countFunctionInvocations` would only see an anonymous function without a name.

```js
const map = new WeakMap();

function countFunctionInvocations(func) {
    const fn = (...args) => {
        map.set(fn, (map.get(fn) || 0) + 1); // use returned function in Map
        return func.apply(this, args); // invoke passed function
    }
    return fn;
};

const add = countFunctionInvocations(function add(x, y) { return x + y });
const inc = countFunctionInvocations(function inc(x) { return x + 1 });

add(2,3);
add(1,2);
add(2,3);
add(2,3);
inc(inc(1));
console.log(map.get(add), map.get(inc));
// 4 2
```

Comment: thanks for all this. Is the above a stretch for using the `WeakMap` data type? Are there any consistent/legitimate uses for it, or is it quite rare in production programs?

Comment: It used to be one of the few ways for classes to have good privacy for instance properties via a closure, but that's changed now that private properties are an option. (It's used commonly in transpiled code with Babel) Other than that, I've never encountered a situation when writing my own code where a WeakMap seemed like the right solution - but that's partially a result of my personal style, and I wouldn't rule out never finding it to be the right tool for a job in the future.